# How to fix dispatchUncaugthException in java

Tags: java, arrays

I was trying to generate an array with random numbers, but it continues to show `dispatchUncaughtException`. I am totally new to java, could someone help me to figure this out?

The codes that I wrote are as follows:

```
public class FindfreieGroundwaterlevel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double[] groundwaterDistance = {-0.01,1.2,0,4.5,6.3,8.2,0,-1.7,2.1,0};
        int [] index = new int [groundwaterDistance.length]; 
        int zero = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < groundwaterDistance.length; n++ ) {   
            if (groundwaterDistance[n] == 0) {
                index[n] = n; 
            }else{
                index[n] = 0;
                zero++;
            }
        }             
        int[] newindex = new int[index.length - zero];
        int j = 0;
        for(int m : index) {
            if( m!= 0 ) {
               newindex[j] = m;
               j++;             
            }
        }   
        for (int i: newindex) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }

        Random generator = new Random(10);
        Coordinate[] position = new Coordinate[20];
        for (int i = 0; i <position.length; i++) {
            position[i].x = generator.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("x :" + position[i].x);
            position[i].y = generator.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("y :" + position[i].y);
            position[i].z = generator.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("z :" + position[i].z);            
        }
    }   
}
```

The other class called `Coordiante` is:

```
public class Coordinate {
    public double x;
    public double y;
    public double z;
}
```

And this is an image of the exception I got:

[Exception image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLaEw.png)

Answer (score 2):

Your debugger is stopping at the exception, so you're not getting the exception message. If you continue with the execution, you'd see that you're getting a `NullPointerException`. This is because you've created an empty `Coordinate[]`, and then try to assign values to the `null` elements.

You need to create a `new Coordinate()` in the array. If you create a constructor that takes the x, y, z values it could be as easy as

```
for (int i = 0; i <position.length; i++) {
    position[i] = new Coordinate(generator.nextDouble(), generator.nextDouble(), generator.nextDouble());
}
```

if you don't know how to use constructors, start reading the [basic tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). To continue without a proper constructor, the following code does the same thing

```
for (int i = 0; i <position.length; i++) {
    position[i] = new Coordinate();
    position[i].x = generator.nextDouble();
    position[i].y = generator.nextDouble();
    position[i].z = generator.nextDouble();
}
```